# What are the pros/cons of building on the default Quartz.Net database structure

Tags: database, database-design, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

My company is working on creating a scheduler for our employees to use.

Two of my colleagues wish to use the provided Quartz.Net database to add information about the projects that will be getting run. (eg. User interface prompt text, parameter value type, are multiple values allowed)

I don't agree with this as the database is a direct mapping to the Quartz.Net library's calls. In my opinion the database only exists as a method to persist schedules and triggers if the computer it's being held on shuts down.

I'm sure the Quartz database shouldn't have any logic in it associated to the projects that will be using it.

I can't really argue my point as I don't have an extensive background in database design.

Could someone help me with the pros/cons of adding to the provided Quartz.Net database schema?

EDIT:

They do not want to modify the existing tables, but want to add extra tables into the database & use these.

Comment: Are you talking about having extra tables in the database, or adding extra columns to the quartz tables (eg QRTZ_JOB_DETAIL) ?

Comment: Extra tables to the database

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there should be a big issue with that, but I would be careful about creating foreign key relationships with the Quartz tables.

The fact that the Quartz tables/triggers by default are prefixed with QRTZ implies that the designers are naming them so that they won't conflict with other tables in the same database, so they must be expecting this.

The cons start if your tables are defining foreign key relationships with the quartz tables, which creates a strong dependency on the quartz tables.

If, for example, you are creating a history table to show when each job was scheduled and you choose to create a foreign key constraint from your table to the QRTZ_JOB_DETAIL table, then this will mean that you would not be able to delete the job (unless you delete the related records your history table).

So it might be better just to create your history table with a column for the job name and not enforce referential integrity.

If you are linking into the quartz tables, you also need to consider what happens if you want to upgrade to a future version of Quartz where the database structure has been redesigned.

One of the major pros is the fact that the information is all in the same place. You have one database to backup and if your system/server crashes and you need to restore from a backup, then you know that the information in your tables and the quartz tables are consistent.

If you have an existing Sql Database and you want to schedule jobs which are relating to the database. In that case, it makes sense to add the Quartz tables to your existing database, rather than maintain two databases.

Comment: Comprehensive answer.